# jQuery Isotope is not aligning large width item in fitColumns layout mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

Im using Jquery Isotope

i have one item width greater than other div. All items align well but the items are not aligning properly under large width element.

http://jsfiddle.net/S5vAG/1381/

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item large">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>

$(function(){
  var $container = $('#container'),
      $items = $('.item');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode : 'fitColumns',
    resizesContainer : true,
    getSortData : {
      fitOrder : function( $item ) {
        var order,
            index = $item.index();

        if ( $item.hasClass('large') && index % 2 ) {
          order = index + 1.5;
        } else {
          order = index;
        }
        return order;
      }
    },
    sortBy : 'fitOrder'
  });

  $items.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // nothing to change if this already has large class
    if ( $this.hasClass('large') ) {
      return;
    }
    var $previousLargeItem = $items.filter('.large');

    $previousLargeItem.removeClass('large');
    $this.addClass('large');
    $container
      // update sort data on changed items
      .isotope('updateSortData', $this )
      .isotope('updateSortData', $previousLargeItem )
      // trigger layout and sort
      .isotope();
  });
});
```

Can someone please explain why this happening or please provide me a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the reason it is behaving the way that it is, is that is what the `fitColumns` option does; the items are arranged in vertical columns one above the other regardless of the size of the items being arranged.

To get a better view of the available layout options and how they look with items of different sizes check out this **[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Y4mUN/22/)**.

It sounds like you may want to try `layoutMode: 'masonryHorizontal'`.

**[Working Example using `masonryHorizontal`](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/S5vAG/1429/)**

```
$(function(){
  var $container = $('#container'),
      $items = $('.item');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode : 'masonryHorizontal',   // Important Bit
    resizesContainer : true,
    getSortData : {
      fitOrder : function( $item ) {
        var order,
            index = $item.index();

        if ( $item.hasClass('large') && index % 2 ) {
          order = index + 1.5;
        } else {
          order = index;
        }
        return order;
      }
    },
    sortBy : 'fitOrder'
  });

  $items.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // nothing to change if this already has large class
    if ( $this.hasClass('large') ) {
      return;
    }
    var $previousLargeItem = $items.filter('.large');

    $previousLargeItem.removeClass('large');
    $this.addClass('large');
    $container
      // update sort data on changed items
      .isotope('updateSortData', $this )
      .isotope('updateSortData', $previousLargeItem )
      // trigger layout and sort
      .isotope();
  });
});
```

Note in the example I changed the width of `.items.large` so that it would look even.

Comment: Thank you very much. There was something more i wanted but your answer is close i will accept that

Answer (score 0):

use `layoutMode : 'masonry',`

fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/S5vAG/1382/

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but i need fitcolumn layout all is working well but wide width is causing problem

Answer (score 0):

[JQUERY ISOTOPE](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) has propery

when there are more cell then it take automatic first cell height and width and assign all cell like according to the first cell

if you want to item width and height greater than other div. then on this item assign custom style and give height and width

i see your css in  http://jsfiddle.net/S5vAG/1381/  and set code in **CSS**

```
.item.large {
  width: 300px;
  background: #2D6;
    height:200px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

like 
**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item large" style="width:200px;height:300px">2</div><!-- you can use your desire width and height -->
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

**and in js**

```
 (function($) {
      var $container = $('#container');
$(window).load(function(){

            // add randomish size classes

$container.isotope({
  itemSelector : '.item',
  layoutMode : 'masonry',
  });
       $container.isotope("reLayout");
    });


})(jQuery);
```

then it set desire height and width and set like other item with different height and width

i have set this code in my client site you can see [here](http://cosmosfactors.com/black-theme-xyfactors36/diseases/The-symptoms-of-Gonorrhea)

it is anew theme of [XYFACTORS](http://xyfactors.com)

but for your problem you see my demo link i have apply this functionality in demo all pages